# Weird use of equality in Coq

Tags: coq, equality

I have a situation that is kind of like this:

```ml
Parameter I : Type.
Parameter V : I -> Type.

Definition convert {k i} (A : V k) (eq : k = i) : V i.
    destruct eq.
    exact A.
Defined.

Theorem convert_eq : forall (i : I) (u : V i) (eq : i = i), convert u eq = u.
Proof.
    intros i u eq.
    unfold convert.
    (* Now what? *)
```

Usually, when working with `convert`, you can call `destruct` on the equality being used.  However, in this case, trying to use `destruct eq` gives an error:

```
Abstracting over the terms "i" and "eq" leads to a term
fun (i0 : I) (eq0 : i0 = i0) => match eq0 in (_ = a) return (V a) with
                                | eq_refl => u
                                end = u
which is ill-typed.
Reason is: In pattern-matching on term "eq0" the branch for constructor "eq_refl" has type "V i" which should be 
"V i0".
```

I'll be honest that I've never really been good with these weird uses of equality in definitions, so maybe my whole approach is just wrong.  But I feel like `convert_eq` should be provable somehow.  Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of thing is possible if equality on `I` is decidable.

```
From Coq Require Import Eqdep_dec.

Parameter I : Type.
Parameter V : I -> Type.

Definition convert {k i} (A : V k) (eq : k = i) : V i.
Proof.
  destruct eq.
  exact A.
Defined.

Axiom eq_dec_I : forall i j : I, i = j \/ i <> j.

Theorem convert_eq : forall (i : I) (u : V i) (eq : i = i), convert u eq = u.
Proof.
  intros i u eq.
  replace eq with (eq_refl i).
  - now simpl.
  - apply eq_proofs_unicity, eq_dec_I.
Qed.

(* alternate proof *)

Theorem convert_eq_2 : forall (i : I) (u : V i) (eq : i = i), convert u eq = u.
Proof.
  intros i u.
  apply K_dec.
  - apply eq_dec_I.
  - now simpl.
Qed.
```

If you can prove that equality on `I` is decidable, then great! Replace the axiom above with a theorem, prove the theorem, and you're all set.

If you can't prove that equality on `I` is decidable, then you could of course assume the law of the excluded middle. Or you could assume/prove a weaker property such as proof irrelevance, or Streicher's Axiom K. See [Coq and Axioms](https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/CoqAndAxioms).

Comment: Decidability is a **sufficient** condition, but not necessary. As long as `I` is a set in the sense of homotopy type theory, i.e., it satisfies the K axiom, you can prove the statement.

Comment: Thanks! Edited for correctness.

Comment: Well, since you say "in general", that still runs the danger that someone will think it's necessary. How about "This kind of thing is possible if equality on `I` is decidable"?

Comment: Sure, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to homotopy type theory. What if `eq : i = i` in `convert_eq` is not `refl`? Then conversion along `eq` could do something nontrivial to `u`.

The lemma `convert_eq` can be proved under the additional assumption that `I` is a set (in the sense of homotopy type theory). (In fact, it is equivalent ot the assumption that `I` is a set, but I am too lazy to formalize that.)

```ml
Parameter I : Type.
Parameter V : I -> Type.

Definition convert {k i} (A : V k) (eq : k = i) : V i.
    destruct eq.
    exact A.
Defined.

(** A set is a type whose identity types are propositions (have at most one element). *)
Definition is_set (B : Type) := forall (x y : B) (p q : x = y), p = q.

(** Note: a type with decidable equality is a set, see HoTT book 7.2.5. *)

(** Now can prove the lemma under the additional assumption. *)
Theorem convert_eq : is_set I -> forall (i : I) (u : V i) (eq : i = i), convert u eq = u.
Proof.
  intros setI i u eq.
  rewrite (setI i i eq eq_refl).
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

An example of a type which is a set but its equality cannot be shown to be decidable is `nat -> nat`.

Comment: Possibly a stupid question, but is a `Set` in Coq a set? (Could we just change the first line to `Parameter I : Set.`)

Comment: Nope, `Set` is `Type₀`, i.e., the lowest level of type hierachy (if we ignore `Prop`). It's called `Set` for historical reasons. Martin-Löf originally conceived type theory as a formal system for Bishop's mathematics (which is based on sets), and also people used to think of types as "some sort of sets" before HoTT.