# Reasoning about non reflexive equalities & type conversions

Tags: coq, beginner, equality

Following-up from the answers to [this question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2142/weird-use-of-equality-in-coq), reasoning about conversions between types that have decidable equalities is somewhat trivial (here I'm taking `nat` as an example for practicity).

```
Parameter V : nat -> Type.

Definition cast_V {m n : nat} (x : V m) (eq : m = n) : V n.
    destruct eq; exact x.
Defined.

Lemma cast_V_eq {m} (x : V m) (eq : m = m) : cast_V x eq = x.
Proof.
    replace (eq) with (eq_refl m); [ simpl; reflexivity | ].
    apply Eqdep_dec.K_dec_set; [ exact Nat.eq_dec | reflexivity ].
Qed.
```

Now, suppose a similar situation but there is an equality that is not `refl`, like the situation below, for instance:

```
Definition cast_ex {m n} (T : Z -> Type) (x : T (Z.of_nat m)) : Z.of_nat m = n -> T n.
Admitted.

Fail Lemma cast_ex_eq {m n} (T : Z -> Type) (x : T (Z.of_nat m)) 
    (eq : Z.of_nat m = n) : cast_ex T x eq = x <: T n.
```

Now, in my case, `cast_ex` and `T` are not opaque, they are real, implemented functions, operating over an specific inductive (list-like) type.

So, my question is: Can one "get rid" of this kind of casting, where `eq` is not a simpl `refl` ? How could I correctly formulate the Lemma `cast_ex_eq` and what would be the correct way to prove something of this sort ?

Comment: not sure what you are looking for? With cast what you usually end up  proving that a certain property `P` is preserved by cast : `(P n x) -> (P m (cast H x))` where `H : m = n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a general answer: you cannot get rid of cast in general without further assumptions because type theory has an interpretation in which such casts may have non-trivial actions, namely homotopy type theory.

You could introduce an assumption that specializes type theory to a setting that prevents homotopy-theoretic phenomena. One such possibility is uniqueness of identity proofs: if $p$ and $q$ are both elements of $x =_A y$ then $p =_{x =_A y} q$. However, it is likely that there is a better solution. If you tell us a bit more about what you'd like to do, perhaps we can suggest one.

Your specific example is actually worse and UIP won't help. There is nothing in there that prevents `cast_ex` from doing something silly. For example, assuming excluded middle, I could replace your `Admitted` with:

```ml
Definition cast_ex {m n} (T : Z -> Type) (x : T (Z.of_nat m))
  (eq : Z.of_nat m = n) : T n :=
 if T n = Bool then false else convert T eq x.
```

That is, if `T n` happens to be `Bool` then `cast_ex` is constantly `false`, otherwise it is the usual conversion along an equality. In this case it simply isn't the case that `cast_ex T x eq = x`, because it could be that `x = true` and `cast_ex T x eq = false`.